# Getting data with jsonp

Tags: javascript, jsonp

I'm using jsonp to get data from a cross-domain server, the content type is text/html. When i load the url https://user.redact.com/address-book?callback=processData in a script tag locally it works and i get the data like this.

```
<script>
function fireThis(obj) {
    console.log(obj)
}
</script>

<script src="https://user.redact.com/address-book?callback=fireThis"></script>
```

But when I upload this code to my server in a .html file and try to run this file from a web server, I got error in the JSON Object and couldn't fetch the data.

Comment: I get an error saying `user.redact.com` can't be found. Is that a fake domain? Can you give a working URL?

Comment: What is the exact error message you get?

Comment: Well `JSON Object and couldn't fetch the data.` is not coming from the code above so..... the api freak out?

Comment: There's no JSON in JSONP. It's just JavaScript, so you shouldn't get any error that mentions "JSON".

Comment: the endpoint requires authentication cookies are also being sent with the request, the error I get is custom server error in an object with a redirect URL field to the login page. But it works fine when I run it locally.